# softlink to Network Location

Tags: command-line, automator, smb, folder-action

does anyone know a trick how to generate a Softlink to a Network folder (smb or nfs)

the idea is that there are some network folders i use regulary, but they usally not mounted .. the soflink i made is (of course) not avaiable because its going to /Volumes/share/... is it possible to trigger the remount via a folder action or something like this to avoid the mounting drama via finder.

currently i'm working arround this by executing a shell script that just mounts the share.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation, and for me it simply works if I drag the network folder in finder with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> held down to create an alias. If the network share is not mounted, it will automatically mount when the link is accessed either by Finder or with most native GUI applications (e.g., my iTunes folder is linked this way and starting iTunes will mount the share).

However, if you meant a symlink instead of an alias, you can certainly create the link (e.g., on the command line with `ln -s /Volumes/dest /path/to/target`) but it will not cause the automount to occur, but rather the directory will just seem to not exist if accessed without the share mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up an `autofs` mount point to your remote share. [autofs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/automount.8.html) will then mount and unmount the shared drive as required.

If you are comfortable with the command time, this [autofs set up script](https://github.com/grahammiln/setup-autofs/blob/master/setup-autofs.pl) can be tweaked to make the required configuration file changes.